# Plotting a surface in Julia

Tags: julia, surface

I'd like to plot a surface in Julia, but using this syntax:

```
f(x)=x[1]-x[2]
```

not

```
f(x,y)=x-y
```

Could you help me do that?

Answer (score 4):

In this case the simplest approach is to use a wrapper anonymous function:

```
(x...) -> f(x)
```

that you can pass to the plotting function instead of your original function.

Now you have:

```
julia> f(x)=x[1]-x[2]
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ((x...) -> f(x))(100, 5)
95
```